# are just trying too

Tags: tense

In the tenses below correct?
I got it from here: https://youtu.be/iyAQlDDp1mo?t=211

> They **are just trying** to provide fodder for more debate during the
>   elections.

If yes, does it mean the activity "**try to provide fodder**" is happening now and going to continue in the near future?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? Provide more detail, please.

Comment: @userr2684291 done, and I hope to understand if simple continuous present is valid here, what does it describe?

Answer (score 1):

"They are trying" is present continuous.

This verb tense is very well covered on numerous websites.

For example, [ef.edu](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous/) goes into great detail, beginning with:

> THE PRESENT CONTINUOUS IS USED:
>   to describe an action that is going on at this moment:
>   ...

so,

> In the tenses below correct?

Yes

> If yes, does it mean the activity "try to provide fodder" is happening now and going to continue in the near future?

Yes

> Why are they using present continuous?

As they explain on... [espresso english](https://www.espressoenglish.net/simple-present-or-present-continuous/):

> Use the simple present for actions that happen in general.
>
> Use the present continuous for actions happening at the moment or current/temporary projects.

In other words, if you are going to say something in the *present tense*, there's a good likelihood you will be using *present continuous*. It's the common, standard way of saying something about the *present*.